# DateTime.TryParse not working as expected

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I am trying to get this date string **09 Apr 2015: 15:16:17** to display in this format **09/04/2015 15:16:17**. This is what I have tried.

```
    DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime();

    string dateString = "09 Apr 2015: 15:16:17";
    DateTime dateValue;
    DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue);
    dtDateTime = dateValue;
```

This is the output **01/01/0001 00:00:00**

I thought the `TryParse` would convert the `dateString` value to the required `DateTime` format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `TryParse` also returns `true` or `false` depending on whether it succeeded, and I think you'll find it returns `false` here.

Comment: i think the `:` after the year is throwing it off. look into `DateTime.ParseExact` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You may need `TryParseExact` with a format string to change that to a date. `TryParse` I think only tries using the current culture format.

Comment: @DLeh, Ah yes! Maybe that colon is the problem. I cannot edit the string going in so I will look into DateTime.ParseExact. Thank you.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth that's not correct. Both functions accept an IFormatProvider to which you can pass the culture you want to use

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hence I said you _may_ need. But thanks, I didn't know that off the top of my head. Either way, custom formatting is required to tell it how to parse.

Comment: just remove the column,, if you're not aware it's there

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, as I look at the documentation, I was referring to the need to provide a format string, which `TryParse` has no overload for. Format can be given based on `IFormatProvider`, which I think will cover culture specific things, but the format string expresses the structure of the string being provided.

Comment: @Coder I am not supposed to edit it, just work with what's there, so I need to figure out how to work around it. Thank you.

Comment: Well you have working solutions then by specifying the format with TryParseExact

Answer (score 4):

You should go with this:

```
DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime();

string dateString = "09 Apr 2015: 15:16:17";
DateTime dateValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, @"dd MMM yyyy':' HH':'mm':'ss", 
       new CultureInfo("en-us"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
    dtDateTime = dateValue;
```

Using `TryParseExact` you can provide a custom date format string to match your input date. In the example above I added that extra `:` after the year.

Also, you must use a `CultureInfo` which can understand your month name; here I assumed you got an english formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format since it's not a standard date format string:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    dateString,
    "dd MMM yyyy: HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dateValue);
```

Also, you should check the result of the call since `TryParse` and `TryParseExact` return `true`/`false`

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` will not work in every case; for english names, you should provide `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or some CultureInfo related to english

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryParseExact` method:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd MMM yyyy: HH:mm:ss", 
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, 
                       out dtDateTime);
```

**Tips:**

- If you use ***MMM***, the month will be treated as if it is in 3 letter format (like *Apr* )
- If you use ***HH*** rather than ***hh*** it means the hour part is in 24-hour format, the it will not fail on parsing 15 as hour