# DateTime.TryParse() returns different results on different computers with explicit culture

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo

I am having a weird scenario where `DateTime.TryParse(..)` is returning different results with a custom culture (en-US) between two different laptops for a MM/dd/yyyy format.

Here is the code:

```
var isDateTime = DateTime.TryParse("07/22/2022", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out _);
```

On my computer, the above returns false and on two other computers, the same statement is returning true. I am expecting this to return true, but I have no idea why it is returning false on my computer. Can anyone provide a clue on why setting the culture explicitly is not working for me?

EDIT - this is on .NET Framework V4.7.2 on Windows 10 with VS 2022.

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core? Windows or Linux? What does `DateTime.Parse` do? `TryParse` hides errors, it doesn't mean there's a different output. Your deployed application may be running in [globalization-invariant mode](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/globalization-invariant-mode.md) and failing because there's no `en-US` culture

Comment: You should use `TryParseExact` with the pattern you want to recognize. Also, have you checked the values of `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` and `DateSeparator` on the different computers?

Comment: I believe you need to use TryParseExact. Look at this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307122/datetime-tryparse-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Why use TryParseExact? `TryParse` isn't broken. We have no idea what is going on. Trying things at random won't fix anything, especially if there's a CultureNotFound exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`CultureInfo.UseUserOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.useuseroverride) property that might affect it on Windows. You can try disable user-overridden settings by using `new CultureInfo("en-US", false)` instead.

Also, the better alternative is using `CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US")` instead because it always return non user-override version of CultureInfo, and it also returns a cached version which is usually faster than instantiating new CultureInfo every time.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-globalization-cultureinfo-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)

Comment: Thank you - your suspicion is spot on. Using `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")` now returns true for the date I am trying to check.